# Почему одно ядро работает быстрее?

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, kernel

Сделал две функции которые запускаю на разных ядрах(изолированых). Функции просто инкрементируют счётчики. Когда один из них доходит до числа 123456789
программа выводит оба счётчика и завершается. В итоге у меня доходит до конца счётчик который считается на 3 ядре а на 2 всегда не доходит. Почему они не одинаковые? В идеале должны одновременно дойти.
Код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы код на bare metal запускаете? Вот то-то же!

Comment: да и на bare metal - идентичные ли ядра в действительности? Или может быть они работают на разных частотах (запросто для x86 ядер последнего десятилетия)

Comment: Разница в несколько процентов (на bare metal) во времени доступа ядер к внешним ресурсам (в вашем случае таким ресурсом будет L3 (или L2?) Cache) это обычное явление. Т.е. да, на практике одни ядра в чем-то немного быстрее, чем другие.

Comment: мы рады что у вас годубенькие окошки, но любим код читать текстом.